# Using material ui in html development?

Tags: html, css, material-ui

I want to know how I can use [Material UI](http://material-ui.com/#/) in my html project.  I want know whether I can implement code from material UI's [git page](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui)

Comment: just add `materialize.css` in your html

Comment: What is the problem you're facing with their documentation?

Comment: Oddly missing any answer after all this time.  Can one make a dummy HTML file with Material?

Comment: see also [Material-UI without React / just with vanilla HTML, CSS & JS? Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59466781/material-ui-without-react-just-with-vanilla-html-css-js-possible)

Answer (score 9):

From what I have understood and read from the web and your question is that no, unfortunately it is mainly based for javascript and it's frameworks and so on. You could, which I am assuming is not what you would want to do, is you could incorporate react within your html by plugging a cdn then writing your react code in another script tag. But, I have found a possible solution, even though it isn't  Material UI, it's somewhat close:

https://getmdl.io/

This is material design light. For example, to create a button just add the cdn and style sources:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
```

Then add your button like so:

```
<!-- Accent-colored raised button with ripple -->
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
  Button
</button>
<!-- Colored FAB button -->
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--colored">
  <i class="material-icons">add</i>
</button>
```

Hope this helps.
Sorry for the almost 4 year delay.

Comment: Does it provide an Autocomplete input?

Answer (score 0):

**Copy-paste the stylesheet  into your  before all other stylesheets to load our CSS.**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" integrity="sha384-wXznGJNEXNG1NFsbm0ugrLFMQPWswR3lds2VeinahP8N0zJw9VWSopbjv2x7WCvX" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function. Specifically, they require jQuery, Popper.js, and our own JavaScript plugins. Place the following s near the end of your pages, right before the closing  tag, to enable them. jQuery must come first, then Popper.js, and then our JavaScript plugins.**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.12.6/dist/umd/popper.js" integrity="sha384-fA23ZRQ3G/J53mElWqVJEGJzU0sTs+SvzG8fXVWP+kJQ1lwFAOkcUOysnlKJC33U" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap-material-design.js" integrity="sha384-CauSuKpEqAFajSpkdjv3z9t8E7RlpJ1UP0lKM/+NdtSarroVKu069AlsRPKkFBz9" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function() { $('body').bootstrapMaterialDesign(); });</script>
```

Answer (score -5):

First you need to install Material ui using NPM

**npm install**

Install with Bower

You can also install and manage Material Bootstrap using Bower

**bower install bootstrap-material-design**

here is link for  instruction giving how to use material ui in html

https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/#getting-started

you will need to add 
material.css and ripple.css file

for js file
material.js
  material.min.js and  ripples.min.js

Comment: the op asked for how to include it in his html file... This does not answer the question